# C2676 error with reference_wrapper and custom class

Tags: c++, reference, find, binary-operators, reference-wrapper

I am working on my C++ home-project and got into trouble with the following `C2676` error:

`binary '==': 'std::reference_wrapper<Interactable>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`

I have this in my World class and I am pretty sure the find is what invokes the above error:

```
void RemoveObject(Interactable* object)
{
    if (!object) return;
    auto itr = std::find(dynamicWorldObjects.begin(), dynamicWorldObjects.end(), *object);
    if (itr == dynamicWorldObjects.end()) return;
    dynamicWorldObjects.erase(itr);
}
```

And my Interactable looks like this:

```
class Interactable
{
public:
    Vector2 Position;
    Vector2 Velocity;
    Shape Shape;

    Interactable(const std::string& path, SDL_Renderer* rend, int id)
    {
        _id = id;
        SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
        _texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend, surface);
        _destination.w = surface->w;
        _destination.h = surface->h;
        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    }

    ~Interactable()
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(_texture);
    }

    void Render(SDL_Renderer* rend)
    {
        _destination.x = Position.X;
        _destination.y = Position.Y;

        SDL_RenderCopy(rend, _texture, NULL, &_destination);
    }

    int GetID() const
    {
        return _id;
    }

    bool operator == (const Interactable& A) const
    {
        return this->GetID() == A.GetID();
    }

private:
    SDL_Rect _destination;
    SDL_Texture* _texture;
    int _id;
};
```

My question is how am I able to resolve the comparison of these reference_wrappers? Am I missing something or my approach went wrong?

Thank you for the input!

Edit1:
My World class starts with this:

````
class World
{
private:
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Interactable> > staticWorldObjects;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Interactable> > dynamicWorldObjects;
    int _id;

public:
    World()
    {
        staticWorldObjects = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Interactable> >();
        dynamicWorldObjects = std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Interactable> >();
        _id = 0;
    }
...
}```
````

Comment: How is `dynamicWorldObjects` defined?

Comment: Certainly `bool operator == (Interactable& A)` should be defined `bool operator == (const Interactable& A) const` and `int GetID()` should be defined `int GetID() const`. That might solve your problem, but not sure.

Comment: You are right I was in a hurry and left them out, thank you for pointing it out.
Edited the post with how it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure about `std::reference_wrapper` but maybe this will help.

The first change needed is this

```
auto itr = std::find(dynamicWorldObjects.begin(), dynamicWorldObjects.end(), 
    *object);
```

`dynamicWorldObjects` is a vector of `Interactable` but `object` (despite it's name) is a pointer, therefore you need `*object`. Or you could change `RemoveObject` so that it takes a reference instead of a pointer. Perhaps this is the better change.

The second change concerns the const-correctness of `Interactable`. This change might not be strictly necessary to resolve the current problem but it will bite you sooner or later, so it should be fixed now.

Change

```
int GetID()
{
    return _id;
}
```

to

```
int GetID() const
{
    return _id;
}
```

and

```
bool operator == (Interactable& A)
{
    return this->GetID() == A.GetID();
}
```

to

```
bool operator == (const Interactable& A) const
{
    return this->GetID() == A.GetID();
}
```

Comment: Even though I tried both method you wrote and even other workarounds, the compiler still says the same error. It's like reference_wrapper can't compare my classes.

Comment: @Sarungard I took the above code and was able to compile it without problems. I had to remove the SDL stuff since I don't have that installed,and I made `dynamicWorldObjects` a global variable but otherwise no problems.

Comment: @Sarungard If you can't get it working then try to produce a [mre] that anyone can try (i.e. with out SDL stuff) that has the error you have, and post it (perhaps as a new question).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!
It was with the wrong implementation of the == operator of Interactable class.
What I did was to define the operator OUTSIDE of the class and made a friendly declcaration INSIDE.

Nevertheless thank you john for the help!